# Скрипт не работает на айфонах

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему данный скрипт не работает на айфонах?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.icon-angle-down', toggleParent);

  function toggleParent() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this)
      .parents('.item.parent')
      .toggleClass('active');
    $(this)
      .siblings('.sub-menu')
      .toggleClass('open');
  }
});
```

Comment: да, вот сайт http://fazendanatural.ru/

Comment: нет, в данный момент я без айфона, с андроид все открывает

Comment: а по-другому нельзя никак проверить?

Comment: А класс `.icon-angle-down` на каком html элементе?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.icon-angle-down', function() { //<- попробуйте так
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this)
      .parents('.item.parent')
      .toggleClass('active');
    $(this)
      .siblings('.sub-menu')
      .toggleClass('open');
  })
});
```

```css
.icon-angle-down {
  cursor: pointer
}

.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="icon-angle-down">1</div>
```

Comment: да, спасибо сработал cursor

Comment: cursor там просто для наглядности. Основная мысль - анонимная функция в событии $('body').on('click', '.icon-angle-down', >> function() <<

Answer (score 1):

Фокус в том, что ребята в Эппл страшно заморочены на accessibility. Поэтому в сафари клик обработчики не работают на элементах, которые семантически не кликабельны. Так что если ваш `.icon-angle-down` элемент - это, например, `div` или `span`, то клик не отработает.

Есть несколько вариантов решить проблему:

1) Самый прямой: Поменять элемент с классом `.icon-angle-down` на кликабельный `<a>` или `<button>`.

2) Css хак: нужному элементу задать `cursor: pointer`, тогда клик обработчики срабатывают. Не проверял я его давно, может уже не работать.

3) Помимо click обработчика добавить onTouchEnd, он будет срабатывать в мобильном сафари. Но иметь два обработчика с одинаковым поведением чревато багами и двойным срабатыванием.

Надеюсь, поможет.